# How to get item id from quote item collection in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart

I am trying to get all item ids currently added in cart.
Here is what I have done so far.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart 
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;  
  }


public function afterAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{
    $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($productInfo as $item){
       echo $item->getProductId();
    }
}
```

But it is not returning anything. I have also used **$item->getId();** but not avail.

Can anybody tell me what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Have you try below answer solution ?

Comment: Sorry, but it was my mistake. I found die(); code on top of the file. I removed that and my own code gave id. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: You should learn to use xdebug, you’ll never have to type ‘die()’ again

Answer (score 0):

Use

> $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

instead of

> $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

Answer (score 0):

```
private $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy $checkoutSession
) {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

public function getCartItemIds()
{
    $cartItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($cartItems as $cartItem) {
        echo $cartItem->getProductId(); //The entity_id of the product            
        echo $cartItem->getId(); //The entity_id of the cart item
    }
}
```

This should help you understand how to best interact with the cart, assuming you are accessing this in the `frontend` area.

Obtain the current `checkoutSession` by injecting a `Proxy` class for the `Checkout\Model\Session` class. This prevents the session being loaded during class construction, and defers loading until it is called in the `getCartItemIds()` method.

The `checkoutSession->getQuote()` method will return an instance of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` which has the `getAllVisibleItems()` method. This method returns items that have not been deleted from the cart, and which do not have a parent (configurable options).

Each cart item has a `product_id` and an `entity_id`. These two fields are different, as one is the identifier for the `quote_item` record and one is the `entity_id` of the `catalog_product_entity` record it relates to, as shown in the example.

Be sure to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to generate the `Proxy` class if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Get quote by customer id :

```
public function getQuoteByCustomerId($customerId, $storeId){
    $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
    $quoteId = $quote->getId();
    if (!$quoteId) {
        $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setIsMultiShipping(false)
            ->save();
        $quoteId = (int) $quote->getId();
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository
            ->getById($customerId);
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
        $quote->setCustomer($customer);
        $quote->getBillingAddress();
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    }
    return $quote;
}
```

Get quote for guest :

```
public function createQuoteForNotLoggedInUser($storeId){
    $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setIsActive(true)
        ->setIsMultiShipping(false)
        ->save();
    $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    return $quote;
}
```

With _quoteFactory define by :

```
/**
* $_quoteFactory
*
* @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
*/
protected $_quoteFactory;
```

You can get quoteId simple by code :

```
$quoteId = $quote->getId();
```